# is iptables-save rule dump deterministic?

Tags: iptables

is the order of the parameters of iptables rule line deterministic in the `iptables-save` output?

`-A CHAIN1 -m mod1 -m mod2 -j CHAIN2` will be always the same, or I can expect it to be `-A CHAIN1 -m mod2 -m mod1 -j CHAIN2` sometimes?

I don't want to dig into sources, maybe someone here already knows.

Answer (score 0):

The match extensions (`-m`) will definitely always have the same order, because the rule pattern you show:

```
-A CHAIN1 -m mod1 -m mod2 -j CHAIN
```

may not have the same meaning and may not have the same behavior as

```
-A CHAIN1 -m mod2 -m mod1 -j CHAIN2
```

For the parameters of each match extension (I mean the param in : `-m matchext1 --param1 val1 --param2 val2`), it is more a supposition made according to a repeated observation, but the order will always be the same, the output order does not reproduce the order the parameters were given on the command line but seems to be the same as the order in which they appear in manpage of iptables.